# How to manually populate ODataQueryOptions from a oData query string in an ordinary ApiController?

Tags: asp.net, odata, asp.net-web-api

I am using an ApiController (not an ODataController) with OData v4, in which there is a Get action taking ODataQueryOptions as a parameter, like the following:

```
public Product[] Get(ODataQueryOptions<Product> queryOptions){
    // Do query ...
}
```

When I send the oData query request to the ApiController as a uri via web api call, the ODataQueryOptions will be automatically populated. However, when the query string is very long, I get exceptions. I believe the exceptions are caused by that the length of the uri exceeds the limit. I am thinking about passing over the odata query string via the request body, instead of via the uri directly, hoping to bypass the uri length limit problem. E.g.,

```
public Product[] Get([FromBody] uriString){
    // var oDataQueryOptions = SomeMethod(uriString);
    // Do query ...
}
```

It seems one can construct ODataQueryOptions using ODataQueryContext and HttpRequestMessage:

```
public ODataQueryOptions(
    ODataQueryContext context,
    HttpRequestMessage request
)
```

ODataQueryContext in turn can be constructed using

```
public ODataQueryContext(
    IEdmModel model,
    Type elementClrType,
    ODataPath path
)
```

I am able to get the model (IEdmModel) and elementClrType (Type). However, I don't know how to get ODataPath from the query uri.

Also, can I construct a HttpRequestMessage using the uri string (which might be very long)?

Again, I am using an ordinary ApiController with OData V4.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1. About generating ODataPath, you can use `ODataPath DefaultODataPathHandler.Parse(IEdmModel model, string serviceRoot, string odataPath)`. The odatapath is the url escaped service root and query options part.
2. The constuctor of HttpRequestMessage is quite straightforward, for example: `new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://example.com")`.

But i'm not sure if you can bypass the query url length limitation with this way. I thought WebAPI OData actually do the same thing with what you are trying to do.